# Jquery Modal only opened once after clicked, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking to trigger different buttons/modals for each of my sections. 
I want on click hit, a modal popup appears with all the article details.

Everything works fine so far but my problem is that my modal is open just once for click.
I was wondering what I have to modify in my Javascript code to make my modal work always open systematically on-click.

Any ideas?
Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/48rd76mp/5/

Snippet code here:

```
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn');
let overlay;
modalBtns.forEach(btn => {

  btn.onclick = function() {
     overlay = this.nextElementSibling
       overlay.classList.add('overlay--open');
  }
})


function closeModal() {
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay--open');
}

function onDocumentKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeModal();
    }
}

function onDocumentClick(e) {
    if (e.target === overlay) {
        closeModal();

    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false);
```

Comment: `closeModal()` is never called so the `overlay--open` class is never removed. The only code that runs is `document.getElementById('YourModalBox').style.display='none'` in the `onclick` attribute, hence the modal is permanently hidden.

Comment: Not when you click the modal close button it's not. *Edit:* that HTML example does not call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Replace **"onclick="document.getElementById('YourModalBox').style.display='none'""** with **closeModal()**  in all close buttons

```js
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn');
let overlay;
modalBtns.forEach(btn => {
  
  btn.onclick = function() {
     overlay = this.nextElementSibling
     overlay.classList.add('overlay--open');
     document.body.classList.add('hidden');
  }
})


function closeModal() {
 overlay.classList.remove('overlay--open');
  document.body.classList.remove('hidden');
}

function onDocumentKeyUp(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 27) {
  closeModal();
 }
}

function onDocumentClick(e) {
 if (e.target === overlay) {
  closeModal();
  
 }
}
 

document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false);
```

```css
body.hidden{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.close-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.topright {
  position: fixed!important;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}


*{ z-index: 999999;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}



body, html{
font-size: 16px;
}


/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
.img-container { 
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding:20px;  
   background-color: white;
   justify-content: center;  
   z-index:0;

}
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.img-container  {
       padding:20px;  
       height: 80vh;   
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.img-container  {
     padding:20px; 
      height: 82vh;   
}
}
#uno{background:purple;}
#due{background: yellow;}
#tre{background:black;}


img {
   position:absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
   height:100%;
   z-index:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
  img {
        width:95%;
           height:80%;
        object-fit: cover;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
 img {
        width:95%;
        height:100%;
        object-fit: cover;
}
}





.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 20px;  
  right:20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}


.sticky-button {  
  background: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  /*padding: 6px 10px;*/
  color:white;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: auto;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.sticky-button {
     width: auto;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.sticky-button {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  
   }
}


.sticky-button-description {
   color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.75);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight:400;

   font-family:helvetica;
   display:inline;
    letter-spacing: normal;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.sticky-button-description{
    
   }
}
.sticky-button-break {
   padding:0.3rem;
  }
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/







.break{height:200px;
   width:100%;
   background:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;}

.break-2{height:900px;
   width:100%;
   background:red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;}













.btn-1 {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 24px;
 color: white;
 background-color:#3E3E3E;
 padding: 10px 18px;
 font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 transition: transform .3s ease;
     z-index:100;
}

.btn-1:active {
 transform: scale(10.9);
   opacity:0;
    z-index:20;
   transition: transform .3s ease;
    z-index:100;
 
}


.btn-2 {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 24px;
 color: white;
 background-color:#3E3E3E;
 padding: 10px 18px;
 font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 transition: transform .3s ease;
   z-index:50;

}

.btn-2:active {
  position:sticky;
 transform: scale(10.9);
  z-index:50;
   
}

.btn-3 {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 24px;
 color: white;
 background-color:#3E3E3E;
 padding: 10px 18px;
 font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 transition: transform .3s ease;
    z-index:30;
 
}

.btn-3:active {
 transform: scale(10.9);
   z-index:30;

}


/* Modal */
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;/*rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);*/
  pointer-events: none;
}


.overlay, .modal {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.overlay--open {
  opacity: 1;
 
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.overlay--open .modal {
  opacity: 1;

  transform: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;

  width: 100%;
  margin: 15vh auto 0;
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
  transform: translateY(80%) scale(.8);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, 0, 1.3);
  transition-delay: .4s;
  text-align: center;
 font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:400;
}
/*MODAL TRIGGER*/
/*MODAL TRIGGER*/
```

```html
<!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1-->
<!--SECTION-1-->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->  
<div class="img-container" id="uno">
<img src="https://assets.vogue.com/photos/5cd30b6bd2f46d2eca29ab09/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/virgil-abloh-vogue-june-2019-issue.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky">
<div class="sticky-button">      
<!--MODAL-1-->  
<button class='btn-1 modal-btn'>Open Modal</button><div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox">
  <span onclick="closeModal()" class="close-button topright">&times;</span><div class="modal"><span>
  Title Description-1  <br>
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-1-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1-->
  

  
  
  
  
  
<!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2-->
<!--SECTION-2-->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->  
<div class="img-container" id="due">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/ec/76/90ec76614129cba11f178821e59a99f8.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky">
<div class="sticky-button">      
<!--MODAL-2-->  
<button class='btn-2 modal-btn'>Karl info</button><div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox2">
  <span onclick="closeModal()" class="close-button topright">&times;</span><div class="modal"><span>
  Title Description-1  <br>
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-2-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2-->  
  

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
<!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3-->
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->   
<div class="img-container" id="tre">
<img src="https://media.gq.com/photos/5da1fd854e024d0009825bfd/4:3/w_2520,h_1891,c_limit/pharrell-williams-cover-gq-november-2019-02-16x9.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky"><div class="sticky-button">
<!--MODAL-3-->  
<button class='btn-3 modal-btn'>Tomoaki Nagao info</button>
<div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox3">
<span onclick="closeModal()" class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal"><span>Title Description-3  <br>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-3-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3-->  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
<!-- REMOVE!! -->
<div class="break-2"></div>
<!-- REMOVE!! -->
```

Comment: Great @Libin Prasanth Work perfectly!

Comment: Any ideas of what I should add to avoid the scroll when the modal is open?

Comment: add overflow: hidden; when popup opened and remove once it closed, see the above edited code